# How to configure outbound-socket-binding for SMTP mail in wildfly swarm for using yaml?

Tags: email, smtp, wildfly-swarm

I am porting an application from Wildfly 10.0.1.0 to Wildly Swarm 2017.7.0.

Everything went rather smoothly except for the SMTP e-mail configuration using YAML:

I tried some alternatives, but here is the latest one based on what I think the yaml would be from standalone.xml mapping - project-defaults.yml

```
swarm:
  socket-binding-groups:
    mail-socket:    
      outbound-socket-bindings:
        mail-smtp:
          remote-host: smtp.someprovider.com
          remote-port: 587

  mail:
    mail-sessions:
      smtpSession:
        jndi-name: java:/smtpSession
        smtp-server:
          username: username_here
          password: password_here
          tls: true
          outbound-socket-binding-ref: mail-smtp
```

However I still get error:

```
2017-08-05 11:17:36,100 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "mail"),
("mail-session" => "smtpSession") 
]) - failure description: {
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.outbound-socket-binding.mail-smtp"],
"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.mail-session.smtpSession is missing [jboss.outbound-socket-binding.mail-smtp]"]
}
2017-08-05 11:17:36,155 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.outbound-socket-binding.mail-smtp (missing) dependents: [service jboss.mail-session.smtpSession]
```

------------------ Edited August 7th, 2017 -------------------

As advised by Ladicek I tried this:

```
 swarm:
   socket-binding-groups:
     standard-sockets:
       mail-socket:
         outbound-socket-bindings:
           mail-smtp:
             remote-host: smtp.someprovider.com
             remote-port: 587
```

and

```
swarm:
  socket-binding-groups:
    standard-sockets:
      outbound-socket-bindings:
        mail-smtp:
          remote-host: smtp.someprovider.com
          remote-port: 587
```

and

```
swarm:
  socket-binding-groups:
    standard-socket:
      outbound-socket-bindings:
        mail-smtp:
          remote-host: smtp.someprovider.com
          remote-port: 587
```

However neither is working, still have the same error.

Could anyone please help on this?

---------------------- SOLVED ----------------------------

Need to upgrade to 2017.8.1 and use the below configuration

```
network:
  socket-binding-groups:
    standard-sockets:
      outbound-socket-bindings:
        mail-smtp:
          remote-host: smtp.someprovider.com
          remote-port: 587
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved:

Need to upgrade to 2017.8.1 and use the below configuration

```
network:
  socket-binding-groups:
    standard-sockets:
      outbound-socket-bindings:
        mail-smtp:
        remote-host: smtp.someprovider.com
        remote-port: 587
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, I believe there's one level of the YAML structure you're missing: you need to select the socket binding group to which you add the socket binding. That's an artifact of WildFly's managed domain, which is a concept that doesn't apply to Swarm, yet you sometimes run into it. There's only one socket binding group in standalone WildFly and hence in Swarm: `standard-sockets`.

So the YAML will look like:

```
swarm:
  socket-binding-groups:
    standard-sockets:
      mail-socket:
        ...
```

Also for any kind of questions about the Swarm YAML structure, consult https://reference.wildfly-swarm.io

Comment: Thank you for the help, however still not working. The reference does not help much also for outbound-socket-bindings.

Comment: Ah, right. Forgot that this is about outbound socket bindings, those were only added recently. And you're right the reference has nothing about socket bindings, too bad. Glad you made it work, though!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

yml File:

```
swarm:
  mail:
    mail-sessions:
      mail-socket:
        jndi-name: java:/mail/NGSoftMail
        smtp-server:
          username: sigafco@xxxmail.com.co
          password: *****
          outbound-socket-binding-ref: mail-smtp
        debug: true
        from: sigafco@xxxmail.com.co 

  network:
    socket-binding-groups:
      standard-sockets:
        outbound-socket-bindings:
          mail-smtp:
            remote-host: xxxmail.com.co
            remote-port: 25
```

java File:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("mailsender")
public class MailSender {

  @Resource(mappedName = "java:/mail/NGSoftMail")
  private Session session;

  @GET
  @Path("mail")
  public String sendGet() throws Exception {
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

    message.setFrom();
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("david.vasquez@xxx.com.co", false));
    message.setSubject("asunto!!!");
    message.setSentDate(new Date());
    message.setContent("contenido!!!", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");

    Transport.send(message);

    return String.format("{\"your_mail\": \"%s\"}", "OK");
  }
}
```

pom file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```